# Rookie mysql join question

Tags: mysql, left-join, join

I have:

- a `coupons` table with a column called `owner_id` and `id`
- and an `owners` table with a column called `id` and `website_url`.

I'd like to get `owners.website_url` using only `coupons.id` (which is provided in a php variable `$coupon_id`.

Here's my best shot:

```
SELECT owners.website_url
FROM owners o
LEFT JOIN coupons c
ON o.id = c.owner_id
WHERE c.id='$coupon_id'
LIMIT 1
```

Is this correct? I put `LIMIT 1` beacause there are many coupons per owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks correct, but it's pointless to use a `LEFT JOIN` there since you are filtering away the failed joins in your `WHERE` clause. Just use `JOIN`.

You also shouldn't need the `LIMIT` clause since all coupons should have unique ids (assuming that `id` is a primary key) and each coupon has only one owner.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Is that because I limited it to 1? Is the limit 1 necessary?

Comment: @Andypandy: it is not necessary since 1 coupon always belongs to 1 and only 1 owner

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT o.website_url
      FROM coupons c
INNER JOIN owners o ON o.id = c.owner_id
     WHERE c.id='$coupon_id'
```